# How to be RESTful with Django without using form?

Tags: django, forms, rest

I have a page that culminates in three buttons: a checkout button, a change-qty button, and a cancel button:

```
<button name="checkout" onclick="location.href='/checkout/'"    >checkout  </button>
<button name="change"   onclick="location.href='/change-qty/'"  >change qty</button>
<button name="cancel"   onclick="location.href='/cancel-order/'">cancel    </button>
```

I'm doing these redirects in this fashion, instead of using a form, because I want each button to redirect to a different Django view.  The code above works fine, but isn't RESTful: "checkout" and "cancel-order" change the system's state, and so I'd like these to be POSTs.

I could achieve this by having the "checkout" and "cancel" views auto-post special-purpose forms to two new views that take POSTs.  But that's so much screwing around and complexity-adding.  I could also add some jQuery to the page, and have each of those buttons trigger a POST on a hidden form pointed toward the appropriate views, and achieve the same thing.  But that, too, is an awful lot of extra code for something that seems pretty simple.

Really, if there was something like a 'method="post"' on a button, that would be perfect.  But there isn't.  Is there some elegant pattern for achieving what I want?  Or am I doing something very stupid and I just don't know it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jquery-ujs`, and add "data-" attributes to your links:

```
<a href="/change-qty/" data-method="post">change qty</a>
```

etc. the unobtrusive JavaScript will inject the correct code into your link/button/whatever.

Comment: Perfect!  And so succinct!  Thanks very much.